# Set Environment Variable with Spring Boot Gradle plugin and IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

My question is about environment variables.
I am using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin and developing in Intellij 14 on Windows.

I'm trying to get some Pub/Sub example code for Google API's working, but I don't think this is the main point of my question (Noted here since I could be wrong!)
If not running on AppEngine, the sample code has a number of ways that you can satisfy it by supplying a file with authentication credentials.  I currently have no plans to use AppEngine.

I am asked to set an **environment variable** named GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and after some small amount of hair-pulling I've learned that a system property will not suffice.  It must be an environment variable.

I would like to do this in a way that adjusts the environment for only this IntelliJ project and not for everything on the machine.  Normally in IntelliJ I would do this by adding the environment variable to the launch configuration options.
Since I am using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin, I have a **'bootRun'** launch configuration for my project.
The launch configuration options screen has the following major options:  Name, Gradle Project, Tasks, VM Options, Script Parameters, Before Launch

There is NO option for Environment Variables.

I am aware that I could probably fix this problem by doing one of the following:

- Add the environment variable under the windows system control panel
- Stop using the Spring Boot plugin so that the 'Environment Variables'
  section of the launch configuration options comes back as an option

What I am hoping is that there is another option I'm not aware of due to my lack of knowledge about Spring [Boot] and/or Gradle.

Comment: try gradle wrapper, it use bat/bash script to run gradle. You can set your environment variable there, but this is only available for process run by gradle, if you start your AppEngine via gradle then this should work. See example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/gradlew.bat

Comment: Thanks, I will look into gradle wrapper.  As far as I know I have no intention of using AppEngine, just Google Pub/Sub with gmail.  I've edited my question to include this detail.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to do this from the command line. You need to set the `bootRun.systemProperties` to the gradle's system properties.

This is how to do this in `build.gradle`:

```
bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties
```

and then you can just run:

```
gradle bootRun -DGOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/json
```

Comment: every time I set-up a new project with gradle and spring, I forget about `bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties`. thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

In the Gradle Spring Boot plugin, you can set environment variables as an array of key:value pairs.

```
bootRun {
    environment = ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "[PATH TO JSON]" ]
}
```

Comment: How to set environment variables to database?
i have app.properties with ${dbUrl}, ${dbUsername}
./gradlew bootRun says that could not resolve 'dbUrl' in value "${dbUrl}"

Answer (score 1):

Set your environment variable in gradle like below

```
test {
       environment "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "<path_to_json>"
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the environment variable in the build.gradle below:

```
test {
    environment "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "${project.file("/src/test/resources/service-account-data.json")}"
     }
```

hopefully, this helps someone out. Enjoy!

Comment: what's test? does it have some special meaning? It doesn't exist in my build.gradle